# Warning: package needs dependence on R

Tags: r, cran

When `check`ing a package, even on efficiently compressed data (i.e. using `save(iris, file = "somedata.RData", version = 2, compress='xz')` sometimes we see:

```
* checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... WARNING
  Warning: package needs dependence on R (>= 2.10)
```

What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be missing a declaration of which R version your package `Depends` on in `DESCRIPTION`

In the case above where

```
Warning: package needs dependence on R (>= 2.10)
```

simply add this line to `DESCRIPTION`

```
Depends: R (>= 2.10)
```